# How can I compile and run Java classes in Atom on Windows?

Tags: java, atom-editor, javac

In Linux it is easy to compile and run Java files in the terminal with:

```
$ javac App.java
$ java App
```

Is there a way to do this in Windows specifically in Atom editor?
I downloaded `platformio-ide-terminal` package and it opens a terminal, but when I run `javac App.java` it gives me this error:

```
javac : The term 'javac' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ javac App
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (javac:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It would be helpful if I can run the java code in Windows without and IDE and without going to Linux in a virtual machine or dual boot, as we have to use the command line to run and compile java for our first semester CS course.

Comment: Do you have the Java compiler on the PATH? What if you run javac in the windows prompt?

Comment: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  It gives this error, it does not work in Windows cmd.

Comment: Ya, you have the JDK installed incorrectly. Either run the installer again, or manually add the JDK to the PATH in your environment variables.

Comment: I suggest using an IDE such as IntelliJ or Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with Atom. You have the JDK installed incorrectly. The JDK isn't on the Windows PATH, so it can't find `javac`.

Either run the installer to let it fix the PATH for you, or [manually add the JDK to the PATH yourself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm#GUID-96EB3876-8C7A-4A25-9F3A-A2983FEC016A).